# Neo4j speed of failure

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using embedded Neo4j with Java and generating queries automatically that vary in the number of relations they try to match and whether these relations are optional or not. This is an example of a query with optional relations:

```
   MATCH (target:C4)-[rvara:IN_LOCATION]->(nvara:LOCATION) 
   OPTIONAL MATCH (nvara:LOCATION)-[rvarb:CONNECTED]->(nvarb:LOCATION)
   OPTIONAL MATCH (nvarc:LOCATION)-[rvarc:CONNECTED]->(nvara:LOCATION)
   OPTIONAL MATCH (target:C4)-[rvard:HAS_VALUE]->(nvard:TRUE)  
   RETURN DISTINCT target, FILTER(x IN [rvara, rvarb, rvarc, rvard]      
   WHERE x IS NOT NULL ) AS collected
```

I've noticed that when there is no match found, the query engine can take a long time to determine this. When there is a match found, it finds this much more quickly though the search space should be the same; at least I assume they both have to check all possible matches to return results whether they are empty or not. Is there a way to get a query to fail more quickly if it will not match anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run this query with `EXPLAIN` in the browser, you get the plan.

Notice all of those "node by label scan" at the top of the plan.  I think the reason it's taking a long time is that if the query will fail and generate nothing, it has to scan all nodes with a particular label over and over.  If the query succeeds, since it's `OPTIONAL MATCH` I think it only needs to find one match.  So finding one (and skipping the rest of the scan) is always going to be faster than scanning the same population of nodes over and over.

[image]

Comment: That sounds like it could be right. Thanks for the suggestion and explanation.